# Set HttpParams object in HttpClient 4.0

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am creating new HttpClient, by passing ThreadSafeClientConnManager and HttpParams in it's constructor, but it is always throws bad request error.
To figure out what went wrong I had debugged it but all in vain. Provide me with some solution
Here is my code block

```
sc.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
sc.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

HttpParams basicParams = new BasicHttpParams();
ThreadSafeClientConnManager connmgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(basicParams, sc);
ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(
    basicParams,
    // if we have more than 5 concurrent leads, good problem to have
    new ConnPerRoute() {
        public int getMaxForRoute(HttpRoute httproute) {
        return 5;
    }
}); 

g_client = new DefaultHttpClient(connmgr, basicParams);

// It's a lead, be forgiving with timeout
g_client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 5000);
g_client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000);
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(basicParams, 2000);
```

when I call `g_client.execute(postMethod);` in my code it is shows 400 status code means something is wrong with my request. If I pass null in my DefaultHttpClient constructor

```
g_client = new DefaultHttpClient(connmgr, null);
```

The client is executing successfully, but it's not right way as I need basic param set `maxconnectionperroute`. I had paste here the doubtful code. Please have a look and help me. I am stuck here.

I am using HttpClient 4.0 version.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using such an outdated version of Apache HttpClient?

Comment: Just one reason because I am using the WebSphere server(don't know the exact version) which only support this httpclient version.

Answer (score 4):

In one of our older projects we do almost exactly what you are trying to do except we set the default max connections per route directly on the `setDefaultMaxPerRoute(int)` method in `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` (without the need for setting params in the way that you do).

Also, I believe that `ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(basicParams, 2000)` is equivalent to (and can be replaced with) `g_client.getParams().setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.TIMEOUT, 2000);`.

Example alternative code:

```
SchemeRegistry sc = new SchemeRegistry();
sc.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
sc.register(new Scheme("https", 443, SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));

ThreadSafeClientConnManager connmgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(sc);
connmgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5);  /// Alternative approach to yours ///

DefaultHttpClient g_client = new DefaultHttpClient(connmgr);
g_client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 5000);
g_client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000);
g_client.getParams().setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.TIMEOUT, 2000);   /// Alternative approach to yours ///
```

Comment: This is how id solve the problem as well. Id probably wrap the connection manager in a service though.

Answer (score 1):

Create the object with the default (working) constructor.
Then modify the properties of the object as defined in the Apache HttpClient documentation for the version being used. Example for 4.5:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html

For managing things like max connections per route, take a look at that (different classes involved) documentation:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html